# How do I stop spam / bots from hitting my rest api?

Tags: ajax, rest, captcha, bots, spam

I have a button that a user clicks for a game I made.  Each time the user clicks the button it sends a request to my rest api, increments a counter, stores the count in my database and returns.  The objective of the game is to click the button as many times as possible.

The request looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/increment',
      success: handleSuccess
    }
```

What I'm concerned about is someone writing a script that spams the `/increment` rest endpoint and boosts their score.

I though about using a `captcha` but I'm afraid that will make my site hard to use and look bad.

Are there any other ways to stop a script / bot / spammer from hitting my rest endpoint?

Comment: You could try a `robots.txt` file (http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html). That, or require some sort of "human validation" cookie.

Comment: You could require a login with a captcha, then allow normal access after that for that logged in user-

Comment: @CaseyFalk Spammers totally ignore robots.txt, though.

Answer (score 0):

If requesting a login for your users or solving a captcha is not an option, you could log the IP of that request as well and stop incrementing for some time (for example 24 hours) if its done by that IP again. To get some convenience for your human users you cold send a warning-message as well if on is hitting it again within your time limit.

This method is not perfect, as in large university or company networks there are possibly more users sharing an IP address, but depending on your audience this method could be OK enough. Its a compromise which should work well enough as a trade off between convenience (no login/captcha) and no spam (some users my under rare conditions not able to save their score).